# How to handle own jars through svn in maven

Tags: maven, svn, jar, dependencies, external

In my project, I'm referring to my own `jar` files and some 3rd party `jars`. All of them are kept inside a `ProjectLibrary` folder. After, I want to distribute them via `svn`. Can someone guide me on how to handle these library dependencies through `maven`? Is it better to use a remote repository? I want to use this dependencies without going for any other framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should host a nexus repository to hold your own artifacts, and let maven talk to it to download your own libraries (just like third party libraries)

Comment: I want to have a remote repository and also local repositories for each developer machine. If there is no a jar that the project is depending in the user's local repository, it should be downloaded and installed to local repository. How do I do it.

Comment: set up a `sonatype nexus` upload your own libraries to that nexus repository and point your maven to look at this nexus repository as well by adding `<repository>` tag to `pom.xml`

Comment: should this sonatype nexus repository is located as a remote repository or local repository?

Comment: its remote repository but still under your controll under your own subnet

Comment: then all the time we have to access when a user is building the project. I want to reduce the network traffic as well. Isn't there a way to handle a copy of that remote repository in the local machine when a user is synchronizing  the project via svn?

Comment: maven will handle it by itself, when it has local copy it won't look for remote repository

Comment: Does that means, once local repository automatically download the jar file which is not in the local repository from the remote repository and install it into the local repository by it self?

Comment: yes exactly, also it has update policy controlled by settings.xml if you want to timeout local cache and force it to lookup remotely after certain time period you can configure that

Comment: How should I install all my jars in the different sub folders inside my main projectLibrary folder to nexus repository without harming to the folder structure?

Comment: you can upload it through GUI

Comment: I want to use this sonatype nexus inside my network. So can I use the GUI to upload the libraries and install them?